# How can I tell if no arguments have been given and nothing is coming in on stdin?

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I'd like a Perl script that I'm writing to display a help message if it receives no input.

How can I tell if nothing is coming in on stdin?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you mean by "nothing is coming in".  If I run your script and I don't type anything for 5 minutes, does that qualify?  What if I start typing after 10 minutes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (@ARGV == 0 && -t STDIN && -t STDERR) { 
    print STDERR "$0: WARNING: reading input from keyboard, type ^D for EOF, ^C to intr.\n";
}
```

Comment: The idiom is available in a maintained and documented module: http://p3rl.org/IO::Interactive#is_interactive()

Comment: @daxim: I’m afraid that that is the very sort of thing that I *don’t* like. **At all.** It is neurotic to the point of nutty to suck in some blasted CPAN module that you cannot rely on being there, especially when the PurePerl™ version is simple, clear, and well established.  If I were looking for Java, I do know where to get it. It’s like telling people to use some dumb slurpy CPAN module because the speaker gets panic attacks over the Perl builtin variables: that’s *their* own problem, and they should not make it ours by suggesting a “cure” that is worse than their own insecurity about Perl.

Comment: I knew it would make you uncomfortable. I'm afraid your opinion is a minority one, and every programmer of intermediate skill knows the arguments in favour of using a module.

Comment: @daxim: Bah!! You go far too far to impugn my Perl programming skill: it looks foolish. Plus since when is the majority ever right? Sheep are sheep, even when led off the cliff. Every programmer of *basic skill* knows the arguments in favor of actually bothering to understand the language they happen to be using, not to mention something that works anywhere.  What you use **does not work everywhere,** and just confuses people.  Let them learn real Perl before going on from there, because **otherwise they will never be able to maintain other people’s code.**

Comment: @daxim: every programmer of intermediate skill knows the arguments in favour of using a module _when there is enough functionality to abstract away_. Frankly, in this case, you are going overboard with modularization (let's call it Java syndrome, or overdesigning).

Comment: Arguing is no fun in these limited text boxes here. I'll have to discard most of what I've written and leave it at one retort: You found an omission? That's fine! [File a ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Create.html?Queue=IO-Interactive). With the next release my code using IO::Interactive will be better without me lifting a finger, while yours using the raw primitives will not. Isn't abstraction and specialisation great?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Instead of printing a warning I'm printing the full help message. This gives my script the option to be "piped to", given a filename, or be interactive, and if the user just types the name of script it prints the help message.

Comment: Beating a dead horse here, but: I don't think it was wrong for @daxim to mention the module. He certainly didn't word the original comment in a way to deserve the response you gave. Sure, in this specific question, it's not the best solution for something so trivial, but I've come across questions where the PurePerl answer wasn't the best for *my* situation, and a comment mentioning a relevant module was perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

`$#ARGV` contains the number of arguments.

http://www.devdaily.com/perl/perl-command-line-arguments-read-args

Comment: `$#ARGV` contains the index of the last element of `@ARGV`, that is, the number of arguments minus one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about input from STDIN, you can check if the variable is equal to the empty string (after removing the CR/LF).  For example:

```
my $myInput = <STDIN>;
chomp($myInput);
if ($myInput eq "")
{
    print "Error! You didn't submit any data!\n";
}
```

However, as [@thnee says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166811/how-can-i-tell-if-no-arguments-have-been-given-and-nothing-is-coming-in-on-stdin/7166870#7166870), if you are checking for the arguments passed in via command line, you should use $#ARGV.

For example:

```
if ($#ARGV == -1)
{
    print "Error! No input arguments entered!\n";
    exit(-1);
}
```

References:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: It was [thnee](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166811/how-can-i-tell-if-no-arguments-have-been-given-and-nothing-is-coming-in-on-stdin/7166870#7166870) who mentioned `$#ARGV`. Also, you should avoid referring to other answers as "above" (or "below"), because equally-scored answers appear in random order. Instead, add a link to the referenced answer.

Comment: The test `$myInput eq ""` tells you whether the input was an empty line, not whether there was no input (depending on just what the OP means by "no input").

Answer (score 0):

You might also find this perldoc FAQ useful for checking whether there is any input from the keyboard:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-check-whether-input-is-ready-on-the-keyboard%3f

Comment: If the script is run with stdin from the keyboard, there won't be any input available until the user gets around to typing something.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-find-out-if-I'm-running-interactively-or-not%3f fits the question better.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to check if something *has* come in on STDIN (using a nonblocking read, `select` or `ioctl FIONREAD`), but it's impossible to check if something *is* coming in on stdin, since it hasn't happened yet.

Impossibility aside, you're asking to break convention. For example, take `cat`, `perl`, `sort`, etc, etc. If you provide no arguments, they'll happily wait on STDIN until you provide what they need.

The user knows to use `man tool` or `tool --help` to get info.

Comment: What, you think `ioctl(STDIN, $FIONREAD=0x4004667F, $long=pack(L=>0))` might get them into too much trouble? :)

Comment: @tchrist, I have no idea what that does. Is that a third way of seeing if data is available?

Comment: Yes, it's how to see how many unread bytes there are on that descriptor. But you have to get the ioctl number correct for your system, and you have to then use an unbuffered and not-encoded raw `sysread` on however bytes it returns. You cannot mix that with stdio calls because it only checks the pending kernel buffer, not anything already sent to user space. `FIONREAD` is the "File I/O Number of pending unread bytes to READ" ioctl. See Stevens. Its one of those questions whose answer falls in the "you really don't want to know" category.

Comment: @tchrist, I'll add it to the list, but it doesn't change my answer.

Comment: No, of course not. That's why I smileyed it.  You use this sort of thing to decide whether to read keyboard input in non-canonical modes.

Comment: @tchrist, You'd use something similar when using `select` with writers cause `select` doesn't tell you how many bytes can be written without blocking.